# AttributeError: module 'fut' has no attribute 'Core'

Tags: python, pycharm, attributeerror

I'm pulling my hair out soon. I get the error:

> File "/home/*****/PycharmProjects/Futbot _hako_ny/FUT/Central.py", line 27, in main
>   core_class = fut.Core('******@hotmail.com', '*****', '*****', platform='ps4',sms=True, proxies=proxy,anticaptcha_client_key=captcha_key)  # Setting up core class
>   AttributeError: module 'fut' has no attribute 'Core'

I know there is an attribute `Core` in the module `fut`. I tried:

```
print(fut)
<module 'fut' from '/home/*****/PycharmProjects/fut/fut/__init__.py'>
```

and I can see that it is using the correct module path. Everything was working fine, until I imported a self-made module into the `core.py` and added a print-statement. If I outcomment my import and small change to the `core.py`, then everything is working fine again.

Why does an import / small change breaks my program? Pycharm doesn't complain about any of my imports or code.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you import your own module with `*`? Does it maybe contain another `fut`?

Comment: Maybe you did confuse the upper and lower case?

Comment: @MichaelButscher, I import it like this `from FUT import Central`, I tried changing the name of FUT to FUT2, just in case the same name in caps isn't allowed. Otherwise, there is no other 'fut', I have tripled checked that. @Megalng the spelling is correct

Comment: `print(dir(fut))` may help. You should call it before and after importing your own module and compare.

Comment: good call, this is the output without my changes: `['Core', 'EAHashingAlgorithm', '__author__', '__author_email__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__copyright__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__license__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__title__', '__version__', 'config', 'core', 'exceptions', 'log', 'pin', 'urls']`

Comment: and this is with my changes: `['EAHashingAlgorithm', '__author__', '__author_email__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__copyright__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__license__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__title__', '__version__', 'config', 'exceptions', 'log', 'pin', 'urls']`. I must ruin something in the library, because the `Core` disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The error was caused by circular dependency. My module "core.py" was importing the module "Central.py" and vice versa. In the fixed version, I moved the "`import Central`" into the function that was using it.